# Why do double square brackets create a DataFrame with loc or iloc?

Tags: python, pandas

Comparing:

1. `df.loc[:,'col1']`
2. `df.loc[:,['col1']]`

Why does (2) create a DataFrame, while (1) creates a Series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in principle when it's a list, it can be a list of more than one column's names, so it's natural for pandas to give you a DataFrame because only DataFrame can host more than one column. However, when it's a string instead of a list, pandas can safely say that it's just one column, and thus giving you a Series won't be a problem. Take the two formats and two outcomes as a reasonable flexibility to get whichever you need, a series or a dataframe. sometimes you just need specifically one of the two.